# Windows10+VS2015+UWPでの標準コンパイラとは

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml

タイトルの通りなんですが、
UWPでコンパイルする時、csc.exeを使っているのでしょうか？

csc.exeの応答ファイルの中を見たんですが、
相変わらずsystem～から始まるのを参照しています。Windows.UI.Xamlとかありません。

あるいは、拡張子「.winmd」を集めた応答ファイルの行方でも構いません。

ご存じの方いたらご教授お願いします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

応答ファイルとはres、リソースファイルのことでしょうか？

前提としてcsc.exeは通常のコンソールアプリケーションです。なのでcsc.exe自身は`System`で始まる.NET FrameworkのDLLを参照していますし、特に指定しなければこれらのライブラリをビルド時にも使用します。
しかしUWPプロジェクトのビルドを行う場合、csc.exeのコマンドラインに`/nostdlib`オプションを指定することで.NET Frameworkへの参照を排除し、`/reference:`オプションでWinRT側のDLLが参照設定に追加されるようにプロジェクトとテンプレート(≒`.csproj`)やProgram Files内の`.targets`ファイルで構成されています。このため`UWP`用のアセンブリをビルドすることが可能になります。

UWPのコンパイル時に何が行われているか詳しく知りたければ、Visual Studioの「オプション」ダイアログの「ビルド/実行」ページでMSBuild プロジェクト ビルドの出力レベルを変えれば出力ウィンドウにすべてのコマンドラインが表示されるようになりますので、参考までにどうぞ。